# Bypass XMLHttpRequest overriding

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, overriding, deobfuscation, hcaptcha

I want to make hcaptcha solver Chrome extension. I am successfully using some api to solve captchas, find `data-sitekey` and another params.

But exactly on [Hcaptcha's site](https://dashboard.hcaptcha.com/signup) there is a block that I currently can't bypass.

It overrides (with obfuscation) `XMLHttpRequest` and, in particular, `send` method allowing requests only to some domains, and I, obviously need to send request to custom domain, so when I try to do that, it throws an exception.

**My try**

In extension I have two files - `content.js` and `inject.js`.

`content.js` just injecting `inject.js` *before* page loads:

```
function injectScript() {
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("charset", "UTF-8");
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('inject.js');
s.onload = function() {
    //this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).prepend(s);
}
injectScript();
```

In `inject.js` there is an `interval` that tries to find and parse captcha's data need to solve it, and after parse send to solver server via Ajax request.

I tried different methods, adding at the beginning of `inject.js`:

1. Variable that contains yet indeed original `XMLHttpRequest` - `var dihdkn278dm = XMLHttpRequest` and then creating not `XMLHttpRequest` but `dihdkn278dm` object;
2. Variable that contains yet indeed original `XMLHttpRequest` object - `var dihdkn278dm = new XMLHttpRequest()` and then instead of creating request object use it;
3. Variable that contains `XMLHttpRequest` `send` function (yes just `native code`).

However, when it comes to call `send` in the code, it is already overwritten.

Ideas how to bypass it? Only inspect obfuscated code?

*`fetch` also overridden

Comment: Send a message to your content script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198)) which will call fetch/XMLHttpRequest, then send a message with the result. Content scripts are isolated so these will be the original builtins.

Comment: @wOxxOm, yeah, thought about this